# Why is ArcGIS for Desktop not joining records when values have dot (.) in text string?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins, formatting

ArcGIS is not joining records from a table that have a dot (.) in the text string.  Has anyone else come across this problem?  Is it a known issue?

Comment: What are your source files from SDE is should handle the dot? more likely an issue with single files (csv, shape)

Comment: The join table and the feature class it is being joined to are both coming from a geodatabase.

Comment: Asked also on the Esri forums: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/88955-Issue-with-joining-text-containing-dot-character

Answer (score 1):

I just ran the test below using ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 SP1 (the code can be easily modified for 10.0 if you are using that instead).  It shows that Join Field works as expected when the join_field has values with an included period (".") in at least this test example. I recommend running the test to see that periods should be OK to use and then think about what may be different about your data and/or procedure that may be causing it to "break".

```
import arcpy

# Create test geodatabase
if arcpy.Exists("C:/temp/test.gdb"):
    arcpy.Delete_management("C:/temp/test.gdb")
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management("C:/temp","test.gdb")

# Create test feature class with a field (KeyField) filled with values containing a period (".")
arcpy.CreateFishnet_management("C:/temp/test.gdb/fishnet1","1 1","1 2","1","1","5","5","#","#","#","POLYGON")
arcpy.AddField_management("C:/temp/test.gdb/fishnet1","KeyField","TEXT","#","#","#","#","NULLABLE","NON_REQUIRED","#")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("C:/temp/test.gdb/fishnet1","KeyField",""""key." + str(!OID!)""","PYTHON_9.3","#")

# Create test table with a field (KeyField) and one row with value "value.23" for that field
arcpy.CreateTable_management("C:/temp/test.gdb","testTable","#","#")
arcpy.AddField_management("C:/temp/test.gdb/testTable","KeyField","TEXT","#","#","#","#","NULLABLE","NON_REQUIRED","#")
arcpy.AddField_management("C:/temp/test.gdb/testTable","ValueField","TEXT","#","#","#","#","NULLABLE","NON_REQUIRED","#")
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("C:/temp/test.gdb/testTable",["KeyField","ValueField"])
cursor.insertRow(["key.23","value23"])
del cursor

# Join the table to the feature class using the KeyField - for output expect only one feature to have a value (value23)
arcpy.JoinField_management("C:/temp/test.gdb/fishnet1", "KeyField", "C:/temp/test.gdb/testTable", "KeyField","ValueField")
```